# How do you unit test globally registered Vue Components?

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, vuejs2, jestjs, frontend

I have a repo where people usually use Vue.component as the way to write components, not even exporting them as an ES6 module (It was before SFC's were a thing). Is there any way to extract that Vue.component registration and unit test it, without refactoring it at first?

Just like this:

```
Vue.component('knife', () => {...});
```

I see that this wouldn't be the best solution because we WILL have namespace pollution over that Vue global instance, and at some part the unit test might become a huge instance because of that, but I just wanted to know if there's a way to do it.

Since we are going to unit test some of those components we could refactor them as a SFC, and the tests would guarantee that they still work.

If you're just going to say: "don't do this", please at least show more issues for not doing it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Since we're using Jest, we could use a [setup file](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#setupfiles-array) to define Vue as a global var, and access it's API to get the globally registered components:

Setup file:

```
import VueGlobalInstance from 'vue';
// Forcing Vue to be a global var to use it on the global components.
global.Vue = VueGlobalInstance;

// This is where we can reach those Vue components.
// Vue.options.components
```

So on your component.js file:

```
import '@/component.js';
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils';

describe('Component', () => {
    let props = {
         ...
    };

    const build = () => {
        const wrapper = mount(Vue.options.components['component-name'], {
            propsData: props,
        });

        return {
            wrapper,
        };
    };

    it('renders the component', () => {
        const { wrapper } = build();

        expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
    });
});
```

This is an edgy case, and you shouldn't do that at all IRL, because of global namespace pollution.